# Explorer can't be started running "explorer.exe" and doesn't open folders on double click

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-registry

On my developing pc I modified `HKCR\*` `HKCR\Folder` and `HKCR\File` to register own context menus.

Suddenly my explorer.exe showed this behavior:

- can't start explorer running "explorer.exe" (Shows "unknown error")
- can't start explorer with windows+E (Shows "unknown error")
- **can** start explorer witch "explorer.exe c:\"
- can't change folder (double click) when explorer is started (nothing happens)

What I have tried so far:

- Import the modifies keys from another W7
- Reporting the registry accesses with "procmon" and compared them with a working system

**Edit**
**My Changes:**

- under `HKCR\folder\shell\MenueForMyExe\command` I added the path to my Exe. (..\MyExe\ %1)
- same under `HKCR\file` and `HKCR\*`

Worked fine, but I saw that a doubleclick on every folder opened my Application. So I deleted the three keys. After that the described problem began.

**Edit2**
The problem persists for every user, even after restarts

Comment: Unless you share exactly what you did, one can only assume, your modifications are the reason for the error.

Comment: @ramhound Yes, I will try to recap my changes and edit the post

Comment: Did you try relogging or restarting? Technically, restarting explorer from the command line isn't a supported scenario.

Comment: @surfasb Yes, and tried it with different users

Comment: `HKCR\files` doesn't even exist on my machine.  I'm assuming you meant `HKCR\file`. Did you happen to change the values for the `(Default)`?  Mine is set to `Folder` for `HKCR\Folder`, `URL:File Protocol` for `HKCR\file`, and not set for `HKCR\*`.

Comment: @GuitarPicker `file`is correct ... changed the post. I didn't change the default values. Verifeid them with a helthy system => ok

Answer (score 0):

You could spend weeks, trying to figure out what little thing you did wrong.

Just use system restore, then try again.